# Oracle ODBC driver on Solaris 10

Tags: sql-server, oracle, odbc, driver

I want to install oracle ODBC driver on Solaris 10, for to connect from Oracle Database to SQL server database.

It appeared very difficult for me...

Can you help me?

Thank you very muck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I googled [oracle database link solaris sql server](http://www.google.de/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=oracle%20database%20link%20solaris%20sql%20server) and found [this](http://www.easysoft.com/applications/oracle/database-gateway-dg4odbc.html)

Perhaps that's what you need. No idea if its viable.

Answer (score 1):

Third party ODBC providers are often a better solution [OpenLink Software](http://uda.openlinksw.com)

Answer (score 1):

See the [OpenLink Single-tier ODBC Driver for Oracle](http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-oracle-st/) .

(Single-tier means client only (Solaris) install)

You will, however also need to install the Oracle Instant Client on the client (Solaris) machine.

This [Quick Start Guide](http://wikis.openlinksw.com/dataspace/owiki/wiki/UdaWikiWeb/SingleTierInstallQuickstartUnixOracle) will detail how to install, configure and test (for an accomplished Unix user)...